# upgrade Apache kafka from 2.7 version to 3.X without zookeeper on production kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

we have production Kafka cluster with 2.7 version , 5 Kafka brokers on RHEL 7.9 version

we want to upgrade the Kafka version to 3.X version

3.X version not include zookeeper , so we are wondering if we can do upgrade without any data loss

regarding to kafka 2.7 version , Kafka storing the metadata on zookeeper servers ( as brokers ids , topics names etc )

but is it possible to perform rolling upgrade from 2.7 to 3.x version without any data loss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [upgrade guide](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_zk_3_3) should contain all infos you need.

While KRaft mode (without ZooKeeper) is production ready since 3.3, they still keep ZooKeeper around for compatibility until the 4.0 release.

Furthermore If I understand correctly, it is currently only possible to set up a fresh cluster in KRaft mode, but not to migrate an existing one with ZooKeeper. Kafka 3.5 will be a migration version they intend you to migrate from ZooKeeper to KRaft.

This is explained quite nicely in the release notes from Kafka, especially for [Kafka 3.3](https://blogs.apache.org/kafka/entry/what-rsquo-s-new-in) and the [release video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUwwNnVyc4c&t=227s)

As long as your Kafka brokers are not running with Java 8 still, you can simply do a rolling upgrade from 2.7 to 3.X like you are used to.

Comment: regarding to what you said "As long as your Kafka brokers are not running with Java 8 stil" from which java version we can do the rolling upgrade ?

Comment: I always went to Java 11 directly. I looked it up though: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=181308223 Apperently it is only marked deprecated but will continue to work with Java 8 until Kafka 4.0 drops support. Forgive me for being wrong on this one.